# Series of functions and uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

> Find an example of a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n \in \Bbb Z_+}$ of real-valued functions defined on any metric space $X$ such that the series $\sum_{n \in \Bbb Z_+} f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, each $f_n$ is uniformly continuous but $f$ is not.

**My Attempt**

Let $X = ]1, 2]$ with the usual Euclidean Metric, then define:
$$f_n(x) = \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)^{n}$$
which is uniformly continuous for every $n \in \Bbb Z_+$ because it is actually Lipschitz on ]1, 2] (it suffices to check that the derivative is bounded above).
Now, it is easy to verify that:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \Bbb Z_+}f_n(x) = \frac{x}{x-1}, \forall x \in ]1, 2]$$
however, near $x = 1$, $f$ explodes to infinity more rapidly than a linear function, hence it can not be uniformly continuous (one can also check it by contradiction).

Is this argument good enough?

As always any answer or hint is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: Everything is correct but I am not sure if arguments concerning uniform continuity are precise enough. I don't know what kind of arguments are used in general. If you are sure about that then rest is fine. Although $f_n = x^n$ on interval $[0, 1)$ would have also did the job and should be easier to work with.

Comment: You are right, I was not clear enough on the argument concerning the non-uniform continuity of $f$, however I did not want to fill the answer with an epsilon-delta proof (although I did it on my own) and so I preferred a qualitative argument for anyone to check. Anyway, thank you very much for the proposed example!